# Complicated latex table

Tags: tables

[image]

I would like to create a table like this. I am new in latex, so this is very complicated for me. Please someone help me out. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: For a starting point you might read [the wikibook's tables section](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).

Comment: And imho, this table doesn't look good but rather unstructured. Are you sure you want to recreate it?

Comment: Yeah, I am. I need a table like this.

Comment: Then build a table like this. And if you encounter a **specific** problem in the process, ask a question about **that** problem. This site is not for Do-it-for-me-questions.

Comment: Skillmon's "rather unstructured" is a mild way of putting it. It's an absolute dog's breakfast. The classification that this table tries to convey would be more clearly represented in the form of two or more bulleted lists, some of them nested (but don't go more than 3 levels deep). If you stick with the table, at least give it some structure with table cell borders. Pull the non-tech-specific column before the tech-specific one, and remove the silly bullets.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer thanks for clarification of my point. I tried to be diplomatic there :)

Comment: I agree with the previous commenters who noted that the design of the table shown in the screenshot is exceedingly poor: it's both highly confusing and needlessly cluttered. Such a design should be avoided at nearly all cost. Should you succeed in recreating such a dreadful table, do be prepared for the following, unfortunate outcome: the readers of your document will sadly have no idea at all what it may be that you're trying to tell them.

Answer (score 1):

I am not experienced in making tables but this is what I came up with using tablesgenerator.com. I couldn't get "Market-based" centered vertically but maybe this approach gives you some inspiration.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Put caption here}
    \label{my-label}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Market-pull policies}} &  &  &  \\ \midrule
     &  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Technology-specific (direct)}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Non-technology-\\ specific (direct)\end{tabular}}} \\ 
     &  &  &  &  \\ 
     &  & Price-driven & Quantity-driven &  \\ \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Market-\\ based\end{tabular}} & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investment\\ incentives\end{tabular}} & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investment\\ subsidies\\ Tax credits\\ Supportive tax policy\\ Tenders (price)\end{tabular}} &  \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tendering systems\\ for investment\\ grants (quantity)\\ Quotas (capacity)\end{tabular}} & \multirow{4}{*}{Emission trading} \\  
     &  &  &  &  \\ 
     &  &  &  &  \\
     &  &  &  &  \\
     &  &  &  &  \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
     &  &  &  &  \\
     &  &  &  &  \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```